# Creating nested elements in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to create a component that integrates with a reactive form. Since this specific field will be reused several times throughout the app, it would really help me out if I managed to make it. The idea is, I have the form in a page (it's an Ionic project), this page will contain the FormGroup. Inside this page, I will insert the component, passing to it the FormGroup, and the path leading to it.

The form:

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        group1: new FormGroup({
          group2: new FormGroup({
            control: new FormControl('')
          })
        })
      });
```

If I, for example wanted to pass down the control 'control' to the component, 
I'd use the @Input() directive to pass the form variable and another variable that would look something like this:

```
[
  {ctrl: 'group1', type: 'group'}, 
  {ctrl: 'group2', type: 'group'}, 
  {ctrl: 'control', type: 'control'}
]
```

Inside the component the result should be this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div [formGroup]="controlPath.ctrl[0]">
    <div [formGroup]="controlPath.ctrl[1]">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input [formControl]="controlPath.ctrl[2]"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

The problem, I can't think of anything that could help me with making the formGroup divs without writing them out manually. If anyone knows an easier way to do it, I'd appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need a recursive component.
First, change the format of your data a little to make it recursive:

```
[
  {ctrl: 'group1', type: 'group', children:
                        [ {ctrl: 'group2', type: 'group', children: 
                                        [{ctrl: 'control', type: 'control'}]}
]}]
```

basically add a children array if if it a group.

now you component can be defined as: nested-form-component

```
       <div *ngFor='let item of formInfo' >
         <ion-item *ngIf='item.type==='control' >
            <ion-input [formControlName]="item.control"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
          <div  *ngIf='item.type==='group' [formGroupName]= "item.control" >
         <nested-form-component   
           [formGroup]="form.controls[item.control]"  [formInfo]= "item.children" > 
         </nested-form-component>
        </div>
      <div>
```

I give the component 2 inputs, a formGroup instance  **form** and a `formInfo` which is the above re-formatted data.

Now in your hosting component,

Generate the formGroup instance **form** based on the data **formInfo**, and in the template, insert

```
  <form  [formGroup]="form">
     <nested-form-component  [formGroup]="form"  [formInfo]= "formInfo" > 
         </nested-form-component>
   <form>
```